# Multiple Jquery Cycle Slideshows with their own Navs

Tags: jquery, cycle, nav

I am using the Jquery cycle plugin (http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/) on a blog listing page.  There are multiple slideshows which work fine but I'd like each on the have their own previous and next.

Because these are blog posts it is difficult to sign unique IDs or classes.  I currently have:-

```
    $('.article .gallery').cycle({
 next: '.viewmore .left',
 prev: '.viewmore .right',
timeout:0
});
```

I have tried the following but doesn't work.  It gives you a better idea of what I am looking for:-

```
 $('.article .gallery').cycle({
 next: $(this).next('.viewmore .left'),
 prev: $(this).next('.viewmore .right'),
timeout:0
});
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Dave.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$('.article .gallery').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.cycle({
        next: $this.next('.viewmore').find('.left'),
        prev: $this.next('.viewmore').find('.right')
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I have tried this in my site but it doesn't seem to work.  I am going to have a go again tonight with a simple cycle. Will get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

can you use entry ids in the classes/ids?

something like:

```
<span id="prev_{entry_id}">Previous</span>
<span id="next_{entry_id}">Next</span>
```

then put that portion of the javascript inline.